# openvpn/anyconnect: certificate failed. How to get the pub certificate to add to my vpn client

Tags: vpn, openvpn

Our IT has misconfigured the sertificate to our vpn server. When I try to connect I get:

```
Server certificate verify failed: certificate does not match hostname
SSL connection failure: Error in the certificate.
Failed to open HTTPS connection to vpn.foo.bar.de
```

(the certificate they use is for *.bar.de ...) I do not want to always have to select to ignore this as was suggested to me :S... When I click details, [image]

I get a bunch of details about the key...
[image]

Is there a way to save the public key and use it?